# IE11 JS XMLHTTPRequest/XMLParser discards <body> attributes

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

So I have an AJAX call which returns a complete XHTML document.  In IE, when I get the XMLDocument from ajax.responseXML, all of the attributes on the body element are missing.  Creating a new DOMParser and re-parsing ajax.responseText gives the same result.  No problems in FF or Chrome.

Using the following workaround for now:

```
var x;
var body = xmldoc.getElementById('body');

if (!body) { //WTF?? IE loses the body's attributes 0.o
    body = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var str = this.ajax.responseText;
    var par = new DOMParser();
    var tmpdoc;
    var attr;
    str = str.substr(str.indexOf('<body'));
    str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('>') + 1);
    str += "</body>";
    tmpdoc = par.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
    attr = tmpdoc.documentElement.attributes;
    for (x = 0; x < attr.length; x++)
        body.setAttribute(attr.item(x).name, attr.item(x).value);
}
```

This is super hacky though, anyone know a better way?

Comment: FWIW, the problem goes away when using Compatibility Mode: IE8.

Answer (score 0):

IE11 have some problèmes with AJAX XMLhttpRequest on the same domain specially on localhost, there is a explanation on [Internet Explorer 11 does not add the Origin header on a CORS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784209/internet-explorer-11-does-not-add-the-origin-header-on-a-cors-request)

Comment: This isn't a problem with XMLHTTPRequest itself, it's a problem with the way it/DOMParser parses the response XML.