# XMLHttpRequest - SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am getting below error when I visit our webpage first time on IE11. It works in Chrome on my machine but doesn't work on other developer's machine. But it works when page is refreshed in all cases.

Error is

SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://secure.server.com/esi?isie789=n&_=1403623253418 required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef1, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef1.
SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request.

It is being called using Ajax jquery.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: esiUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        data: "isie789=" + isIE789,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(responseText) {
            if(responseText.length > 0) {
                $("#deal-of-day-esi").replaceWith(responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
```

Looking into to request/response headers in IE11 - I don't see any. But on refresh or in Chrome, Firefox we do see response headers with 
Below values

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.server.co.uk

Can you please help.

Comment: **Can someone please help us on this please**

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but in my testing it appears that:

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef1

specifically refers to a mixed mode error; for example when an https site serves a request to redirect to an http site.