# Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Error - Can this be blocked at the client?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a web app that performs several CORS operations using $.getJSON AJAX calls. Normally, on most client browsers, this works fine because the server my app is hitting has CORS enabled. However, I noticed today when I attempt to run my app on a client (using IE 11) in a corporate environment with fairly stringent security in place, my CORS attempts are failing, with the following error:

[image]

If the image cannot be read, there are a couple errors.

```
One is SEC7118 (CORS operation
One is SEC7127 (Redirect was blocked) and 
Script7002 (XMLHTTPRequest: Network error 0x2ef1.
```

So, is it possible a client network can prevent CORS operatons?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402376/184546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The corporate network can block everything it wants, and it might be the case that an over-restrictive firewall strips the CORS headers (aka "everything it doesn't know") from the HTTP request/response.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in an AngularJS application, simple but using directives. The resolution was as follows.

Creating a file **staticwebapp.config.json** in the root of the repo and adding the following config worked:

```
{
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS"
  }
}
```

Publish your application and re-test. successfully solved!
Below how my AngularJS is project to project

[image]