# Enabling CORS for Web API in Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Web API project to **Azure Web app**. And from a angularjs app I am trying a $http.get request to the API. but it gives a CORS(cross-origin) exception though I have enabled it in my Web API startup config

```
 app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

I want to Enable CORS for Azure Web App, that would solve the problem I believe

**EDIT**
http://nearestbuyweb.azurewebsites.net/ this is the URL of the Web app. It is trying to access http://nearestbuyapi.azurewebsites.net/api/MenuBar where the exception occurs.

I think it is not possible with Azure Web App. [MSDN Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/48001dd0-bf86-4ebd-9529-2e1afd270e3a/enable-cors-on-azure-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required)

Please help!

Comment: Just to clarify, do you get the CORS exception when your site tries to make an API call to a 2nd site, or do you get it when a 2nd site tries to make an API call to your site?  Enabling CORS on your site will only enable the 1st scenario.

Comment: when I access Web api from my Web project I get the error. I want to basically enable CORS for Azure Web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys,

The issue happens only at my corporate network. Having googled I found that corporate network can be disable CORS requests . Found this here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226013/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-error-can-this-be-blocked-at-the-client)

Answer (score 3):

Note: You use CORS settings to let **other** websites access your site's API. Not to access other site's APIs.

Based on your comments it sounds like you're getting the CORS error when you try to make external requests from your site.  That's exactly the behavior CORS is supposed to block.

For the errors to go away you would have to apply the CORS config settings **on the site who's API you're trying to access**.

In your case you want to make sure you're applying the config changes on the http://nearestbuyapi.azurewebsites.net site. NOT on http://nearestbuyweb.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: That is what I am doing @Zain

Comment: "That's exactly the behavior CORS is supposed to block." - It's not CORS that is preventing your browser from viewing the response, it's the same-origin-policy (SOP). CORS is basically just a bunch of headers you can use to relax the SOP.

Answer (score 2):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: try a request using fiddler or postman for example, and check if it works. I'm using exactly those configuration and is working fine.

Comment: when I access it without origin i.e type the URL in chrome as well as fiddler it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have CORS in Azure working using this:

**WebApiConfig.cs:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "PublicApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
  <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks @buKaneer even I am doing the same configuration. It works perfectly in my local machine ( API and Web hosted in IIS as separate applications), but when I publish to azure It doesn't work .

Comment: Did you deploy your WebApi to Azure Web App or Mobile Services or cloud services ?

Comment: Its a web site hosted on Azure here's the link http://get-json.azurewebsites.net/ CORS calls are made from here http://codepen.io/collection/XzVOeX/

Comment: so  get-json.azurewebsites.net is hosted on Azure , but CORS calls are made to codepen which is not in Azure ? For me CORS calls need to be made to Web Api which is deployed to azure

Comment: You can make a CORS call from any website to get JSON (which is hosted on azure).

Comment: but that's not happening

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nearestbuyapi.azurewebsites.net/api/MenuBar. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://s.codepen.io, http://nearestbuyweb:80', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82686/discussion-between-dhanilan-and-bukaneer).

Comment: I was unable to get CORS in Azure to work as expected - if anyone was able to, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541917/azure-webapp-cors-does-not-add-cors-headers

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the options handler in IIS using web.config.
http://eugeneagafonov.com/post/38312919044/iis-options-cors-aspnet-webapi-en

Comment: I am using Azure Web App where we don't get to modify the IIS

Comment: You're  editing the web.config not modifying IIS directly. Did you follow the link? By the way, this is how I have it working in Azure (web apps).