# Azure WebApp Cors does not add Cors headers

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

I have an Owin WebAPI2 .NET app that I host on an AppService in Azure.

I want to add CORS support using Azure as [in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript). It seems simple, you just add an Origin site to the list like this: http://screencast.com/t/r2ATq4u5

I would now expect the Response headers to contain this allowed Origin.

However, the CORS headers are not included in the Response Headers when I check it with Fiddler:
http://corstestqm.azurewebsites.net/breeze/restaurantsbreeze/basictest

Steps I have tried:

- Stripped out all CORS Nuget libraries from my solution and all traces of CORS code in my API project.
- Deployed to a brand new AppService
- [Enabled Owin Cors](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors) AllowAll

None of these had any effect. (ie. the Response does not contain the CORS header specified in Azure).

Am I missing something really basic here?

**UPDATE**
I simplified the problem even more:
In VS2015, I created a new API project and pushed it to http://corstestbasicap2.azurewebsites.net/api/values/
with no changes (ie. it should NOT have CORS enabled).

I then use [Test-Cors tool](http://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=http%3A%2F%2Fcorstestbasicap2.azurewebsites.net%2Fapi%2Fvalues%2F&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote) to hit that API. It does not get a CORS error as expected. I then go into Azure and add a dummy URL (e.g http://www.example.com) and try the CORS test again. It should fail as Azure should only let example.com through. However, it works fine.

I then [edit CORS again in Azure](http://screencast.com/t/JZFDhQq9kC) and add http://www.test-cors.org below http://www.example.com (so it should let either through) and now the headers return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.test-cors.org` as expected.

But this makes no sense? Surely the previous call should fail when "http://www.test-cors.org" was NOT in the allowed Origins? It does not seem to be doing anything useful?!

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve these by adding in your web.config bellow configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

In global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
  if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
    Response.Flush();
  }
}
```

If you want control from portal, please view bellow image:

Note, according with App Service CORS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript#app-service-cors-versus-web-api-cors) you can not use both Web API CORS and App Service CORS in one API app.  You have to clean your project about Web API CORS

> Don't try to use both Web API CORS and App Service CORS in one API
>   app. App Service CORS will take precedence and Web API CORS will have
>   no effect. For example, if you enable one origin domain in App
>   Service, and enable all origin domains in your Web API code, your
>   Azure API app will only accept calls from the domain you specified in
>   Azure.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ionut, thank you, I had found that the web.config way works, however I want to control CORS with the Azure App Service as each app service slot has different requirements (I know I could do this with debug webconfigs). My question really is WHY does the Azure CORS functionality not work as expected?

Comment: Hi Rodney, you can control Cors headers from portal for each slot: select yuur app, slot and then CORS from blade menu. Have you tried this? I added an image on my response

Comment: Hi Ionut, yes, I have done that, but it does not work (this is what my problem is about - see screenshots links in my original question). It seems to behave very weirdly and plain does not work.

Comment: Hi Rodney, I updated my post according with your needs. Regards

Comment: Hi Ionut, I appreciate the effort, however this was the first step I tried in my question above (stripping out all CORS libraries and ONLY using Azure). It does not work. The Azure App Service cors headers are not emited

Comment: Hi Ionut, 
I removed UseCors from my Startup.cs, used same web.config than yours, and cleared Azure Cors urls in Azure Portal. But azure always put the same Headers (X-LiveUpgrade=1..). Mine are dropped.

Comment: Great, that option exists in the virtual machine?

Comment: Any progress regarding this issue? I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: Hi Lobato, can you tell me please more details about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I accidentally put http instead of https into Azure AD B2C custom page config blade ... After change to https it works like a charm.

[CORS headers missing when deployed on Azure Web App / Azure API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741567/cors-headers-missing-when-deployed-on-azure-web-app-azure-api/50270805#50270805)