# IE11's developer tools returns "Network error 0x2ef1"

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to make an ajax call to a cross-site domain. What happens is that when any request is made to this domain, it does a 302 redirect to another url on the same domain. After this, the console on the dev tools shows the error "Network Error 0x2ef1 ". Does anyone know what does that error message mean?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402376/184546