# Microsoft Edge vs EnableCors (WebAPI 2)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am working on a WebAPI project (my first) and am using EnableCors to limit where my api calls can come from. Just for testing, I did not include "http://localhost" as an allowable url.

In Chrome, I get an error stating localhost isn't allowed access (the expected result) and Microsoft Edge functions normally (no error, unexpected result). Is this an "undocumented feature" of Edge? Or am I doing something wrong that's causing it not to work with Edge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for Microsoft Edge and Microsoft Internet Explorer: they do not include the port number when evaluating the Same origin policy, so `http://localhost:8080` and (e.g.) `http://localhost:8081` are the same origin for them.

This is why Edge do not complains about not finding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response (for it it's not even a cross-origin request).

Reference:
[Internet Explorer 11 does not add the Origin header on a CORS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784209/internet-explorer-11-does-not-add-the-origin-header-on-a-cors-request)