# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient (TypeScript): Do not go to the requests after authentication from CORS

Tags: cors, servicestack

I configured the service as mentioned above:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
      allowCredentials: true,
      allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, Origin",
      allowOriginWhitelist: new[]
             {
                    "http://localhost:4200",
                    "http://localhost:63342",
                    "http://localhost:63342",
                    "http://localhost:3000",
                    "http://my.site.com"
             }));
```

and I have 2 functions Login() and GetContacts()

```
class AppComponent {
***
      constructor(){
        this.client = new JsonServiceClient("http://my.site.com");
      }

      async Login(){

        var auth = new wbs.Authenticate();
        auth.UserName = this.username;
        auth.Password = this.password;

        var authResponse = await this.client.post(auth);

        console.log(authResponse);
      }

      async GetContacts(){
        try {
          this.contacts = await this.client.post(new wbs.Contacts_Get());
          console.log(this.contacts);
        } catch(e) {
          this.contacts = [];
          console.log("Failed to get:", e.responseStatus);
        }
      }
}
```

"servicestack-client": "0.0.36",

I call these functions in turn:

```
1. Login()
2. ContactsGet()
```

if I run locally on IIS express works, but when I deploy to IIS server it's not working. The login runs fine, but in Internet explorere and Safari ContactsGet fails, it returns status 401, but works in Chrome.

Help please in what my error? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

IIS settings

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
var authFeature = new AuthFeature(
        () => new MyUserSession(),
        new[] { new MyCredentialsAuthProvider()
});

public class MyCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider {
        private Userslogic users => Userslogic.Instance;

        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password) {

            if (!users.CheckUserNameAndPassword(userName, password))
                return false;

            var session = authService.GetSession(false);

            session.IsAuthenticated = true;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

AuthRequet:

[image]

ContactsGetRequest:
[image]

Comment: Please post your  entire`AuthFeature` configuration as well as the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers for both the Authenticate Request and the subsequent Request to `Contacts_Get` straight after the Authenticate Request. Also you should only use `client.post(requestDto)` to POST a **Request DTO**, not a string. You can use `postToUrl()` to post to a URL but it needs to match the Route of the Request DTO, i.e. something like `/contacts` and since its a POST it should include a Request DTO for the body. For a `Contacts_Get` Service you likely want to use `client.get(new Contacts_Get())` instead.

Comment: @mythz I updated the question. And You were right, I was not a faithful version of the code: this.contacts = await this.client.post(new wbs.Contacts_Get());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the research of the issue revealed that the problem is on the client and not the server ServiceStack, such restrictions have browsers IE and Safari.

1. IE - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450633/7015077
2. Safari - https://stackoverflow.com/a/486569/7015077

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because the client does not send Cookies with the request and it's not sending them because your CORS configuration is invalid, the `allowOriginWhitelist` URLs need to **match exactly** with the hostname that the request is sent to, in this case is `http://109.120.152.165`.

Whenever subsequent requests in a HTTP Client do not honor the `Set-Cookie` Response Headers of the previous request your CORS configuration is invalid and you need to investigate why that is.

Comment: Thanks for feedback!