# CORS - Get Remote origin/domain name

Tags: ajax, cors

I am doing Ajax call from cross domain.I would like to allow this call only to the specific domains. What is the best way to get remote origin from HttpServletRequest. Will `request.getHeader("Origin")` be available all the time? If remote domain matches I will set

```
origin = getFromRequest...
if (origin=="example.com"{
   response.addHeader("Access-Controll-Allow-Origin",origin);
  }
```

Comment: I found some explanation in here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin. Browsers always add the Origin header to cross-origin requests made with XHR or the Fetch API. But note that browsers also always send the Origin header for same-origin POST requests — and for same-origin requests made with any HTTP method other than GET or HEAD.

Comment: thank you @sideshowbarker for the link. Seems like it is clarifying any cross origin call will have origin header.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found from the link
https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/. I am seeing this as cross domain should have 
`Origin` header all the time
[image]

Also found this link, it is very helpull, it is telling how IE 11 manage cors request [Internet Explorer 11 does not add the Origin header on a CORS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784209/internet-explorer-11-does-not-add-the-origin-header-on-a-cors-request)

Comment: See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-request. (And don’t use https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ for anything; it’s years out of date and doesn’t match current browser behavior.)

Comment: Can somebody tell why answer is down voted? as stated in the answer most of browser do send "origin" and the link saying IE might send diferently.